# dataTable with multi-column ordering with "asc" and "desc"

Tags: javascript, datatable

i have a dataTable with multi-column ordering and it works but I need:

**first column "asc" and second column desc -> how is this possible?**

here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zukii/Lucq6vc5/28/

**in this fiddle the column "Rating" is automatic default sorting "asc" and then the column "Price" should be automatic "desc"**

```
var mytable = $('table.dt-tarif').dataTable({
    "paging":   false,
    "info":     false,
    "searching": false,
    "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],

    "aoColumnDefs": [
        {
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [0]
        },
        { 
            "type": "currency", targets: 3 
        },
        {
            targets: [ 3 ],
            orderData: [3, 4]
        }
    ],

    "language": {
        "lengthMenu": "Zeige _MENU_",
        "zeroRecords": "Keine Entwürfe vorhanden!",
        "info": "Seite _PAGE_ von _PAGES_",
        "infoEmpty": "Es konnte kein Entwurf gefunden werden.",
        "infoFiltered": "",
        "search": " ",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Erste",
            "last": "Letzte",
            "next": "Vor",
            "previous": "Zurück"
        },
    }
});
```

thanks and greetings ;)

Comment: it should be -> best rating with lowest price!

Answer (score 1):

You needs to use a **2D array to achieve multi-column sorting** to archive the result.

```
var table = $('table.dataTable').DataTable();
table
    .order( [ 3, 'asc' ],[ 4, 'desc' ] )
    .draw();
```

further you can change the format [ columnIndex, "asc|desc" ] (e.g. [ 1, "desc" ] for sorting .

> Solution fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ShirishDhotre/a3utn0ek/7/

Check if this help to close your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working perfect now :)

https://jsfiddle.net/zukii/Lucq6vc5/37/

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"currency-pre": function ( a ) {
    a = (a==="-") ? 0 : a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" );
    return parseFloat( a );
},

"currency-asc": function ( a, b ) {
    return a - b;
},

"currency-desc": function ( a, b ) {
    return b - a;
}
} );

jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "currency": function ( a ) {
     var x = a.replace(",", ".").replace("€", "");
     return parseFloat( x );
  }});

var mytable = $('table.dt-tarif').dataTable({
    "paging":   false,
    "info":     false,
    "searching": false,
    "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],

    "aoColumnDefs": [
        {
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [0]
        },
        { 
            "type": "currency", targets: 3 
        },
        {
            targets: [ 3 ],
            orderData: [3, 4]
        }
    ],

    "language": {
        "lengthMenu": "Zeige _MENU_",
        "zeroRecords": "Keine Entwürfe vorhanden!",
        "info": "Seite _PAGE_ von _PAGES_",
        "infoEmpty": "Es konnte kein Entwurf gefunden werden.",
        "infoFiltered": "",
        "search": " ",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Erste",
            "last": "Letzte",
            "next": "Vor",
            "previous": "Zurück"
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:
**"order": [ [ 1, "asc" ], [ 3, "desc" ] ]**,